# What to do with VBA Query Result

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a query within access that selects all the contacts for a particular company based on the CompanyID Field. And on my form i have a selection of labels of which will be populated with the query result. However i'm a little stuck on how i should populate the labels, as there will be more than one contact returned from the query..

The Query

```
ConactData = "SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE CompanyID = " & CompanyValue & ";"
```

Obviously i can do

```
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(ContactData, dbOpenSnapshot)
Me.lblTitle.Caption = rst!Title
Me.lblFirstName.Caption = rst!FirstName
Me.lblLastName.Caption = rst!LastName 
Me.lblEmail.Caption = rst!Email 
Me.lblMobileNumber.Caption = rst!MobileNumber
```

But this will just select the first result from the table, how then, can i move onto the next result? If i'm right in thinking the MoveNext method will simply go to the next record in the table, not the query result?

Answer (score 1):

Why use labels? Just build the form bound to the table.

Then in your code go:

```
Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE CompanyID = " & CompanyValue & ";"
```

This means you don’t need a bunch code to fill out the form, it is done for you. And your example would not allow editing of data either. To write a bunch of code when all the display of data is automatic is a waste of developer time and resources.

In fact, why not leave the form bound to the table, and then use a where clause to open the form

eg:

```
docmd.openform "frmContacts",,,"CompanyID = " & CompanyValue
```

So it not clear why you writing all that code and doing handstands - it simply not required.